# Angular, NGXS. How should I correctly implement subscription for authentication in a state object?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ngxs

I have a tiny problem with subscription.
I actually use NGXS for the first time.
I have found this recipe on their repos:
https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/master/docs/recipes/authentication.md
Followed it and it is almost working.

The problem is when the action `Login` is being dispatched, and the reducer `login()` in the `auth.state.ts` is called, the http request is not actually fired.

It is because of no subscription.
And I don't know how should I correctly make a subscription for the authentication.
If this would be a simple component, I would subscribe in `ngOnInit()` and unsbuscribe on `ngOnDestroy()`, but since this is a state object - then how should I correctly do this?

There is no data to be outputed.
Only the tokens should (access_token and refresh_token) should be stored in localStorage.

What advice can you give me ? Or code example? Thank you in adavance.

Below is my code

```
// auth.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginForm } from '../state/login_form.interface';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService extends ApiService {
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super(http);
  }

  login(credentials: LoginForm) {
    console.log('AuthService:login');
    return this.post('/login', credentials).pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        const jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();
        response.tokenPayload = jwtHelper.decodeToken(response.token);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

```
// auth.state.ts

import { State, Action, StateContext, Selector } from '@ngxs/store';
import { Login } from './auth.actions';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ImmutableContext } from '@ngxs-labs/immer-adapter';

export class AuthStateModel {
  public token: string;
  public refreshToken: string;
}

@State<AuthStateModel>({
  name: 'auth',
  defaults: {
    token: null,
    refreshToken: null
  }
})
export class AuthState {
  @Selector()
  static token(state: AuthStateModel): string | null {
    return state.token;
  }

  @Selector()
  static isAuthenticated(state: AuthStateModel): boolean {
    return !!state.token;
  }

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  @Action(Login)
  @ImmutableContext()
  login({ setState }: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, { payload }: Login): void {
    this.authService.login(payload).pipe(
      tap((result: any) => {
        setState((state: AuthStateModel) => {
          state.token = result.token;
          state.refreshToken = result.refresh_token;

          return state;
        });
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Request is not fired because you're not returing `Observable` in your action handler. `return this.authService.login(payload).pipe(...)` - that's how it should be

Comment: yes, that did work, thank you very much!